# Android 5.0 Naviagation Drawer: Drawer icon not changing back when item selected in drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-navigation

I have the new navigation drawer working for lollipop, I see the new drawer icon (hamburger) and it toggles to <-- (left arrow) icon when the drawer opens and back to drawer icon when the drawer closes. Perfect so far.

When something is selected in the drawer, I'm replacing the main fragment with drawer still in place. I'm able to see the new fragment and the drawer close but still seeing <-- icon, I want to see the drawer icon(hamburger), not the arrow when the main fragment is replaced. How do I control that?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.lollipop.navdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private View container;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    public void setupToolbar(View viewToolbar){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)viewToolbar;
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        container = findViewById(R.id.container);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment())
                .commit();

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new MyFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START|Gravity.LEFT)){
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
package com.lollipop.navdrawer;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{
                        getString(R.string.title_section1),
                        getString(R.string.title_section2),
                        getString(R.string.title_section3),
                }));

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                mToolbar,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return getActivity().getActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

**MyFragment.java**

```
package com.lollipop.navdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private MyActivity mActivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
        mActivity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
        mActivity.setupToolbar(view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: can u plz put ur code

Comment: We will need more code so we can help. You can also check this template for some tips: https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

Comment: @HirakChhatbar, code attached

Comment: @PedroOliveira, code attached

Comment: when you're calling `mActivity.setupToolbar` on your fragment you're telling it your activity to `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. That's why you get the arrow

Comment: @PedroOliveira  If I comment that line of code, I do not see the hamburger icon either. I want to see the hamburger icon when a fragment is replaced.

Comment: Call `mDrawerToggle.syncState();` on that setup function. You might need to add a `getDrawerToggle`getter on your `NavigationDrawerFragment` for that.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `ActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()` on your `setupToolbar` function. Since you don't have access to the `mDrawerToggle` on your activity you will have to create a getter on your fragment and call it like `mNavigationDrawerFragment.getDrawerToggle().syncState();`